# How to implement comparator in java

Tags: java, collections, comparator

This program is to implement comparator

everything is fine

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solocomparator implements Comparator<Solocomparator> {

    int age;
    String name;
    Solocomparator(int age,String name){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public int compare(Solocomparator nam) {
        return (this.name).compareTo(nam.name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Solocomparator> a1=new ArrayList<Solocomparator>();
        a1.add(new Solocomparator(21,"solomon"));
        a1.add(new Solocomparator(26,"solomons"));
        a1.add(new Solocomparator(20,"solomonjking"));
        Collections.sort(a1,new Solocomparator());
        for(Solocomparator i:a1)
            System.out.println(i.age+":" + i.name);        
    }
}
```

in this program i have implemented comparator to sort the arary list by age ,
problem seems to be in this line of code

```
Collections.sort(a1,new Solocomparator());
```

Comment: And the question is?...

Comment: I don't think you mean to compare `Solocomparator` to itself.

Comment: *"problem seems to be in this line of code"* - no, the problem is with the code above it...

Answer (score 2):

`Comparable` and `Comparator` are two different interfaces, used for similar purposes.  `Collections.sort` wants a `Comparator` and this allows you the flexibility to modify the default way objects might be compared (or not, depends on what you want to achieve)

Start by creating a base object, which contains the values you need to store...

```
public class Solomon {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Solomon(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Then create a `Comparator` which can compare the instances of `Solomon` the way you need to...

```
public class SolomanAgeComparator implements Comparator<Solomon> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Solomon o1, Solomon o2) {
        return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
    }

}
```

and/or

```
public class SolomanNameComparator implements Comparator<Solomon> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Solomon o1, Solomon o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }

}
```

Then use either one to sort the `List` of values...

```
List<Solomon> a1 = new ArrayList<Solomon>();
a1.add(new Solomon(21, "solomon"));
a1.add(new Solomon(26, "solomons"));
a1.add(new Solomon(20, "solomonjking"));
Collections.sort(a1, new SolomanNameComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say, but my guess is that your code is not compiling because class `Solocomparator` does not actually implement the methods required by the `Comparator` interface.

You seem to be confusing [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). These are related but different interfaces. A `Comparator` compares two objects that are distinct from the comparator. You would need to implement a method with the signature:

```
public int compare(Solocomparator o1, Solocomparator o2)
```

A `Comparable` object, on the other hand, is one that knows how to compare itself to another object of the same type. This is what you've written, so you probably want your class to implement `Comparable<Solocomparator>`, not `Comparator<Solocomparator>`. You could then sort it with:

```
Collections.sort(a1);
```

If you want to implement a `Comparator<Solocomparator>`, then remove the comparison code from `Solocomparator` and put it in a separate class.